# Can I automatically change the name of the autogenerated wcf proxy?

Tags: c#, wcf

When I add a Service Reference to my project in Visual Studio, it autogenerates a proxy to the service called *ServiceName*Client.  I really don't like that naming scheme.  Is there a way to change it to something like *ServiceName*Proxy?

I can rename the class myself in the autogenerated code, but any time I add new features to the service, and go to UpdateServiceReference, it re-generates the code and changes it back to the old name.

My brief web search uncovered a way to create my own WCF Proxy Generator class, but I'm hoping there is some simple attribute that changes how the class name is calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you, I have been dissatisfied with Visual Studio's code generation of the WCF service reference.  I never have liked the naming scheme, and I also don't want to change it every time I update my service.

To answer your question, I don't know if there's a way to change it or not.  But I had an epiphany after watching [this video](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122) at dnrTV.  Since then, I've been manually coding my WCF client proxies using a naming scheme that fits my project.

Comment: Great Video.  Looks like I'm going to start coding my own as well